# Exporting contact emails to mail

Tags: email, applescript, contacts

i've been trying for a little while now to create a code that will get all the emails for all the people in my contacts, and then put all that into an email in the CC box so that it will send to all the people in my contacts.

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Do you have any code at all?  Some kind of starting point would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
tell application "Contacts"
    set emailLists to value of email of every person
end tell
set bigList to ""
repeat with thisEmailList in emailLists
    repeat with thisAddy in thisEmailList
        set bigList to "" & bigList & (thisAddy as string) & ", "
    end repeat
end repeat
if bigList ends with ", " then set bigList to text 1 thru -3 of bigList

tell application "Mail"
    activate
    set theNewMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:"", content:"", visible:true}
    tell theNewMessage
        make new to recipient at end of cc recipients with properties {address:bigList}
    end tell
end tell
```